# How to install dolphin on Ubuntu 15.10 wily with Unity

Tags: unity, icons, thumbnails, dolphin

I am using dolphin as my preferred file manager under unity. After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10, dolphin shows a couple of problems:

1. some program icons are missing. For example icons in the icon bar for selecting different views (Icon/Compact/Details/Show in Groups)
2. Icons in the configuration windows are missing. For example in the configure dolphin window on the left there is the selection for configuration sections (Startup/View Modes/Navigation/...) Only Startup shows an Icon. The other entries are text only.
3. No thumbnails for any type of file are generated. In "Configure Dolphin/General/Preview" there are only a few options but they do not have any effect. For example if I select images, there are still no thumbnails generated for jpeg files. There is also no option for video files at all. ffmpegthumbnailer is installed. Initially the previews setup window was completely empty. I only got entries after installing kio-extras.

These are the major annoyances right now. I did not find any help through google.

Can anybody explain how to install and setup dolphin under unity for Ubuntu 15.10 in order to make these issues work again. I did not have these problems with the older version of dolphin under Ubuntu 15.04.

the output of "apt-cache policy dolphin" is: 
dolphin:
  Installed: 4:15.08.2-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 4:15.08.2-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 4:15.08.2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Just curious did you try to reinstall dolphin after the upgrade?

Comment: How did you install Dolphin? What's the output of `apt-cache policy dolphin`?

Comment: Sorry for my late reaction. There was no answer for a long time after my original and I stopped monitoring. I have added the output of "apt-cache policy dolphin". And yes, I did purge dolphin and reinstalled from scratch. I guess the problem is that Plasma 5.x KDE applications, or at least dolphin in the respective version is not fully compatible with Unity. That is a pity, because in my opinion Dolphin was the only filemanager that really satisfies my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Besides installing some packages below for Plasma 5 dolphin, I found  using dolphin4 instead of the default dolphin almost completely solves the icon problem. One disadvantage is a blank panel instead of the terminal. You can still press Shift + F4 to open a plain Konsole window in the current directory. But I find no difference in functionality from dolphin to dolphin4.

These are the packages I found so far for a fully functional Dolphin:

To show thumbnails:

> kio-extras

Maybe some of these are needed for video:

> kdegraphics-thumbnailers ffmpegthumbnailer

For the embedded terminal:

> konsole

I just discovered this one to show custom service menus:

> kde-baseapps

And the command to install them all:

> sudo apt-get -y install kio-extras kdegraphics-thumbnailers ffmpegthumbnailer konsole kde-baseapps

Now we only must find out how to show button icons! Maybe some icon package? Anyone? Thanks, Michaël, but oxygen-icon-theme doesn't fix it on my system. Sorry for replying here, I still don't have enough AskUbuntu reputation.

Comment: best not to add a new question within an answer as you efforts might well go unnoticed. If you still have a question to ask, use 'Ask Question' at the top of the page.

Comment: I have and had all of them installed in the latest version. Having these packages does not help with the problems

Comment: Don't know if an update gets notified, so I advice you that I added another solution you may not know.